# Postfix: turning on "smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt" breaks mailman

Tags: encryption, email, postfix, tls, mailman

I have an Ubuntu installation (16.04) where I run postfix as my mail server, and mailman to host a couple of mailing lists I manage. I recently discovered the postfix commands: `smtp_tls_security_level` and `smtpd_tls_security_level`. The recommendation is to set both levels to `encrypt`. This helps cut down on spam enormously because a lot of spambots don't support TLS when connecting to deliver their load of refuse. The mailserver silently drops the connection.

However, `mailman` uses a direct SMTP connection to the local mail server (127.0.0.1), and when the security level is set to `encrypt`, the delivery is silently ignored. The interesting thing is that when I send a message, it gets saved in the `pipermail` archive, but the message is never delivered.

Now, when I remark out `smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt` in the `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file, mailman starts to work again. With the `smtp_...` version on, it does cut down on the volume of spam, but having both options set to `encrypt` is much more effective.

My question: is there a way to get `mailman` to deliver using `postfix`'s `sendmail` binary instead of directly connecting to SMTP? If it would do that, the mail would be delivered just fine and I could have both options set to `encrypt`.

Or does anyone have any suggestions on how I could configure `postfix` to make an exception just for `mailman` and other connections on `127.0.0.1`? I would prefer the former because it's clean, but I want to make this work.

Comment: There are some notes about this on the [postfix website](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#server_enable), although not terribly descriptive. It looks like using the `master.cf` technique you can create a map. Not too sure whether there is a better/easier way to fix that problem otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, I'm hoping for an "easier" solution, but I'll take what I can get. :-)